# :last child override all in vuejs

Tags: html, css

hello i have this in vuejs

```html
<ul class="new-list">
    <div v-for="cat in catss">
        <div>
            <a :href="link(cat)">
                <li class="single-new">
                    <p class="title">{{cat.title}}</p>
                </li>
            </a>
        </div>    
    </div>
</ul>
```

and i have this style

```css
.single-new {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
.single-new:last-child {
    border:none;
}
```

but `.sing-new:last-child` overrid all items and remove border of all 
how can i fix this

Comment: You cannot have anything other than `<li>` as a direct child of `<ul>`. You should fix your HTML

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `<a>` tag? Is it to make the entire `<li>` clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:last-child` always confused, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) explains it

> The `:last-child` CSS pseudo-class represents the last element among a group of sibling elements.

In your example, what you want is the border of the last item in the list is none.

So, you should do this

```css
.new-list > div:last-child .single-new {
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every `li` you have is a `last-child` of an `a` tag.

try i like this

```html
<ul class="new-list">
    <div v-for="cat in catss" class="single-new">
        <div>
            <a :href="link(cat)">
                <li>
                    <p class="title">{{cat.title}}</p>
                </li>
            </a>
        </div>    
    </div>
</ul>
```

```css
.single-new li {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
.single-new:last-child li {
    border:none;
}
```

You should remove all the `div`, `a` before the `li`. directly under an `ul` are supposed to be `li`.

You also should not put `p` (block) inside an `a` (inline). Use `span` instead.

Here is a link about the `inline/block` nature of html elements: [Link](https://codeburst.io/block-level-and-inline-elements-the-difference-between-div-and-span-2f8502c1f95b)

Comment: _"You should remove all the div, a before the li. directly under an ul are supposed to be li"_  perhaps you could lead by example 

Comment: @Phil since there might be restrictions related to `vue.js` which i'm not really familiar with it, i can't give a correct example. If you know how `vue.js` works, feel free to edit my answer. `v-for="cat in catss"` is for the `vue.js` right ?

Comment: That's fair enough. Would need some clarification from OP on how to handle that `<a>` tag. I assume they want the entire `<li>` clickable as a link

Answer (score -1):

I guessed this is what you want

```
<ul class="new-list">
  <div v-for="cat in catss" class="cat">
    <div>
      <a :href="link(cat)">
         <li class="single-new">
            <p class="title">{{cat.title}}</p>
         </li>
      </a>
    </div>    
  </div>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.cat {
  .single-new {
     text-align:center;
     width:100%;
     border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  }
}
.cat:last-child {
  .single-new {
     border:none;
  }
}
```